# c# HttpCliennt GetAsync ResponseHeadersRead Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

**Current Situation:**

System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync with option ResponseHeadersRead is used on client side to stream data from a server.

```
 Dim result = _httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
```

The result will contain a stream which is later written to a file. Because of the ResponseHeadersRead-Option, the data will not be loaded at the first request, but later when the stream is accessed.
However, when it takes more then a few minutes before I read from that stream, I will get a timeout exception at

```
System.Net.ConnectStream.Read
```

**My Question:**

Is there a way to change that Timeout?

Comment: I guess the timeout is on your server side. Try this other URI that will wait 90 seconds before sending the first part of the response: http://heyhttp.org?slow=90000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution myself:

This is the setting I was looking for:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

It is a client side setting.
When using httpclient, it can be set in the following way:

```
  Dim handler As New WebRequestHandler()
  handler.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000
  Dim httpClient = New HttpClient(handler)
```

The default value is 300 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.118).aspx) property?

```
_httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30); // 30 seconds
var result = _httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

Have you used `ContinueWith`:

```
_httpClient.GetAsync(url).ContinueWith(task => { var response = task.Result; ...}
```

Comment: yes, but unfortunately this one has no influence on the described behaviour.